# can there be two signers in an anchor CPI

Tags: anchor, pda, cpi, anchor-lang

I'm writing a program where the program does CPI to metadata which requires two signers?

- can I have two PDA signers in one anchor transaction?
- if so, how?

thank you

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can have multiple PDA signers.

If you notice when passing in a single seed normally, it's wrapped in another array. This extra array allows you to pass in multiple seeds. It looks something like this

```
&[&['seed_1'.to_le_bytes()], &['seed_2'.to_le_bytes()]]
```