# Sign with multiple PDAs in Anchor using .with_signers()

Tags: pda, signing

I want to create an Account using SOL contained in a PDA. For that I guess I need two signatures, the payer(master) that will pay for the CPI call and the rent, and the receiver(subordinate).

How do I achieve that with the .with_signers()?

```
            let rent = Rent::get()?;
        let size = size_of::<Subordinate>() + 8;
        let min_lamport_rent = rent.minimum_balance(size);

        let bump = &[ctx.bumps.surbordinate];
        let seeds = &[b"subordinate".as_ref(), bump];
        let signer_seeds = &[&seeds[..]];

        let cpi_accounts = CreateAccount {
            from: ctx.accounts.master.to_account_info(),
            to: ctx.accounts.subordinate.to_account_info(),
        };

        let cpi_context =
            CpiContext::new(ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(), cpi_accounts)
                .with_signer(signer_seeds);

        create_account(
            cpi_context,
            min_lamport_rent,
            size.try_into().unwrap(),
            ctx.program_id,
        )?;
```

Comment: Duplicate question. An answer can be found here: https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/3002/can-there-be-two-signers-in-an-anchor-cpi/3165#3165

Comment: Is the master account a PDA or a wallet?

Comment: Both are PDA, the question was about how to sign a CPI when multiples signers are involved. Cheers!